# Detecting hidden cells in excel using apache poi

Tags: java, apache, excel, apache-poi

We are using apache poi 3.8 to parse excels. We need to be able to detect (and skip) hidden rows as they tend to contain junk data in our usecases.

It would seem this should work:

```
row.isFormatted() && row.getRowStyle().getHidden()
```

But there never appears to be any row-level formatting (getRowStyle() always returns null). As a last resort we thought checking cell styles might work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
    Cell cell = row.getCell(i);
    if (cell != null && cell.getCellStyle() != null && cell.getCellStyle().getHidden())
        ...
```

But for every row we get (custom output in the above for loop):

```
Cell 0 is not hidden org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle@1b9142d0 / false
```

Does the "getHidden()" not work or does it not work as I think it does? Is there another way to detect hidden rows? (hidden columns would also be a nice bonus but slightly less relevant atm)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`getRowStyle` should normally work as you supposed.

Otherwise, you can check the height of the row, as hidden rows tends to have a height set to 0. 
Using `row.getHeight()` or `row.getZeroHeight()`.

Comment: For hidden rows `hidden` is set to `true` but unless set explicit, `row.getHeight()` always return the default work sheet value which may not be a zero. We can rely on `row.getZeroHeight()`

Comment: The getZeroHeight() works for the usecase I am faced with now. As such my problem is solved although "getRowStyle()" still does not work as it seems it should. Should I flag your response as the proper answer or wait until some gives some feedback on the getRowStyle() issue? (I'm rather new on stackoverflow)

Comment: Normally the row style should be correctly loaded by POI, and thus the `getRowStyle().getHidden()` should work. Or so I think. I assume we can safely rely on `getZeroHeight()`. For the proper answer I don't know. As you wish

Answer (score 4):

After trying a few approaches, `row.getZeroHeight()` worked correctly for identifying hidden row. Also for those who are stuck with Apache POI <= 3.7 version this may be the only solution.