# How to check a column is hidden or not in excel file using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

I am trying to parse a xls file using apache poi. Is it possible to check whether a column is hidden or not. How can I get the width of a particular column.

Example: According to the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10529909/detecting-hidden-cells-in-excel-using-apache-poi) it checks if the row is hidden or not.

Similarly I want to check the width of a column ( or check if the column is hidden or not)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you can **set a column as hidden/unhidden** by using

```
 sheet.setColumnHidden(int columnIndex, boolean hidden);
```

e.g.

```
 sheet.setColumnHidden(2, true);   // this will hide the column index 2
 sheet.setColumnHidden(2, false);   // this will unhide the column index 2
```

and the **column is hidden or not** can be checked using

```
  sheet.isColumnHidden(int columnIndex);
```

e.g.

```
  sheet.isColumnHidden(2);   //this will check the 2nd column index whether it is hidden or not
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Sheet` class has the method [`boolean isColumnHidden(int columnIndex)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#isColumnHidden%28int%29) and also the method [`int getColumnWidth(int columnIndex)`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getColumnWidth%28int%29), however the returned width is a unit of character width. Not sure if that helps you.