# Detect hidden rows when loading Excel file into R

Tags: r

I am using the `xlsx` package to load (a lot of) Excel files into R. How can I detect hidden rows and skip them?

Comment: I highly doubt there are any existing packages that do this. You need to edit the excel file to have a boolean "hidden" column which you can filter by.

Comment: If you happen to know what in the underlying `xml` file sets a row as "hidden" you could file a feature request for this on for example `readxl` (issues page [here](https://github.com/hadley/readxl/issues))

Comment: xlsx uses [apache poi](https://poi.apache.org). All the java methods are exposed to you - so you could just follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17676049/how-to-check-a-column-is-hidden-or-not-in-excel-file-using-apache-poi  and write a function.

Answer (score 0):

There are simple VBA codes to unhide rows and columns in excel. These can be modified to be applied to multiple excel/ sheets or even to an entire folder of excels. hope this works

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. The question seeks recommendations to do this within the R programming language instead of from within excel. Even if a solution with Excel was preferred, your answer does not show how to access the VBA codes and how to change them.

Answer (score -1):

You can get around this in Excel through the "Go To Special..." option when copying and pasting.

1. Select all of the text you want to copy over the hidden rows.
2. On the home tab, editing group, choose "Find and Select" - "Go To Special..."
3. Select "Visible cells only" in the popup and press ok. You should be left with a selection of only the visible cells which you can now copy and paste to another file or sheet, etc.

It doesn't handle it in R but at least could save you some effort.

Comment: Thanks you for your suggestion. But I use R to avoid doing any manipulation in Excel (hundreds of workbooks have to be processed).

Comment: This does not answer the original question at all. You could have suggested it as a comment.